# Solr Keyword Search - Which one is faster - common word (in the index) or uncommon?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an application which connects to Apache Solr server to get search results.
Now, for the application health check I want to hit the Solr core with some random keyword. If this gives me http 200 back, I m marking the system as "Healthy" else otherwise.

So here, all I need is some keyword to query against Solr core and wait for Solr to respond back.

I m not aware about internals of Solr index management.

I m wondering which one of these two will be faster (in getting back the response) -
1. Search for a keyword which is often found in the index data. A very common word.
2. OR search for a word which is unique.

Appreciate the inputs!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [PingRequestHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/PingRequestHandler.html) that is more suitable for a health check. Regarding your question, a unique word would be faster